# OpenGL Multiplying Matrixes

Tags: ios, matrix, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I am working on a 3D 1st person game, using the gyro in the phone, people can look up and down, side to side etc.  I also want to add manual controls to add to this.

This code handles the gyro

```
GLKMatrix4 deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix;
    if (_cmMotionmanager.deviceMotionActive) {
        CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion = _cmMotionmanager.deviceMotion;

        GLKMatrix4 baseRotation = GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f );

        // Note: in the simulator this comes back as the zero matrix.
        // on device, this doesn't include the changes required to match screen rotation.
        CMRotationMatrix a = deviceMotion.attitude.rotationMatrix;
        deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix
        = GLKMatrix4Make(a.m11, a.m21, a.m31, 0.0f,
                         a.m12 , a.m22, a.m32, 0.0f,
                         a.m13 , a.m23 , a.m33 , 0.0f,
                         0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseRotation, deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix);

//        NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", a.m11, a.m21, a.m31,
//              a.m12 , a.m22, a.m32, a.m23, a.m33);
    }
```

I then want to add the manual values for up/down left/up etc.

I can easily add left right

```
deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateZ(deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix, (self.rotateLeft / 20));
```

However when I add up down, it works in north/south direction but east/west direction then rotates on a different axis

```
deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateY(deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix, (self.rotateTop / 20));
```

I have tried to multiple the matrix but that also has the same issue.  It feels like I need to merge them not multiple them

```
GLKMatrix4 leftRotation = GLKMatrix4MakeRotation((self.rotateLeft / 20), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
 GLKMatrix4 TopRotation = GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(-(self.rotateTop / 20), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    GLKMatrix4 complete = GLKMatrix4Multiply(TopRotation, leftRotation);
    deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(deviceMotionAttitudeMatrix,complete);
```

Comment: did you try swapping the order of multiplication?

Comment: Why do you rotate around Y axis when you rotate top? Shouldn't it be around X axis?

Comment: thumbmunkeys you where right, please post so I can mark it as the solution